# An efficient algorithm and code to find cycle in a string in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, string, find, cycle

For example, in "12345123451234512345", what is an efficient algorithm to find "12345"?

Coding in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? If so it would be polite to say. Also, "send me teh codez" questions seldom get good answers. What have you tried? What problems have you run into?

Comment: Question is also not specific enough about what a "cycle" is and when a string has one to be found.

Comment: Is this only numbers? Do you have a clue how big the cycle is? Or how many times it cycles?

Comment: Anyone else smell "NP-hard" from this vague, vague question?

Comment: Yes, it is only numbers. The cycle is hundreds of characters. The string is up to 10,000 characters.

Comment: Do you want the shortest cycle? the longest cycle?  Because I believe the cycle "1234512345" is repeated twice in your example.  And I consider the longest cycle to be superior. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going on your single example:

`12345123451234512345` returns `12345`

I think what you want is to find the longest possible needle that is repeated to complete the haystack, i.e. `1212121212` => `12`, `444` => `4` and so on.

The simplest solution would be to pick the first character and run through the string comparing for matches. If at any point you have a mismatch, pick the first two characters and run through the entire string comparing and so on, until your window size becomes greater than half the string.

Complexity should be O(n^2)

You can optimize which window size you pick based on the length of the string, i.e. the window sizes can only be divisors of the length of the string.

Comment: If you are after the longest possible, is not the string "1234512345" repeated twice in the example?

Comment: @abelenky: The window increases from size 1 onwards, with my algorithm you will stop at 12345 since it will match the entire string =)

Comment: for 444 wouldn't the answer be 44?

Comment: @oxsnarder: Going by his _sole_ example, `44`, `444`, `4444`, `44444`, should all return `4` since he wants the minimum repeating sequence not the maximum.